# (Kotlin) RecyclerView button change outside ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, button, mobile, android-viewholder

I have an adapter class that structures a RecyclerView. I want this RecyclerView to have a button that updates an ImageView outside of the RecyclerView. This code updates the images inside the RecyclerView, but I can't get it to update the image outside.

```kotlin
class CustomAdapter(private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    // create new views
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        // inflates the card_view_design view
        // that is used to hold list item
        val mainXML = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false)
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_design, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view, mainXML)
    }

    // binds the list items to a view
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val ItemsViewModel = mList[position]

        // sets the image to the imageview from our itemHolder class
        Picasso.get().load("https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/x-y/normal/" + ItemsViewModel.text + ".png").into(holder.imageView)

        // sets the text to the textview from our itemHolder class
        holder.textView.text = ItemsViewModel.text
        holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener {

                Log.e("GIF selecter", holder.pokemonSelect.toString())
                holder.pokemonSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                Picasso.get().load("https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/x-y/normal/golbat.png").into(holder.pokemonSelect) //This is the line of troubles, changing it to "holder.imageView" changes the image inside the recyclerview. I want it to change an image outside the recyclerview
            }
        }

    // return the number of the items in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mList.size
    }

    // Holds the views for adding it to image and text
    class ViewHolder(ItemView: View, mainPage: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
        val pokemonSelect: ImageView = mainPage.findViewById(R.id.pokemonSelect)
        val imageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pokemonImg)
        val textView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pokemon)
        val buttonView: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.changeGIF)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try passing a lambda to the `CustomAdapter`? Something like:

`class CustomAdapter(private val changeColour: (() -> Unit), private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>)`

Then, when you want the colour to change outside wherever your other `ImageView` is, you can call something like: `changeColour.invoke()` inside `CustomAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are inflating `activity_main.xml` inside `createViewHolder` which does nothing as it not pointing to the actual `activity_main` instance instead creates a new instance of `View` which is not rendered/attached to hierarchy at all. Even if you set third parameter of inflate to `true`, it would still be child of recycler item not main layout, the ideal way it to pass the required outside `ImageView` in constructor of `adapter`

```
class CustomAdapter(
    private val mList: List<ItemsViewModel>, 
    private val pokemonSelect: ImageView) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
...//in onBind
holder.buttonView.setOnClickListener {
    Log.e("GIF selecter", holder.pokemonSelect.toString())
    holder.pokemonSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    // get rid of holder
    Picasso.get().load("https://img.pokemondb.net/sprites/x-y/normal/golbat.png").into(pokemonSelect) 
 }
...

// In MainActivity

customAdapter = CustomAdapter(list, findViewById(R.id.pokemonSelect))
```

Comment: That worked!! Tysm!!